# unable to run a mariadb 10.1 galera cluster

Tags: centos7, mariadb, galera

I have installed mariadb 10.1 via the instructions here:

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/yum/#installing-mariadb-galera-cluster-with-yum

but when I run the server with :

```
sudo service mysql start --wsrep-new-cluster
```

the server is not run as a cluser:

```
 MariaDB [(none)]> show status like 'wsrep%';
+--------------------------+----------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                |
+--------------------------+----------------------+
| wsrep_cluster_conf_id    | 18446744073709551615 |
| wsrep_cluster_size       | 0                    |
| wsrep_cluster_state_uuid |                      |
| wsrep_cluster_status     | Disconnected         |
| wsrep_connected          | OFF                  |
| wsrep_local_index        | 18446744073709551615 |
| wsrep_provider_name      |                      |
| wsrep_provider_vendor    |                      |
| wsrep_provider_version   |                      |
| wsrep_ready              | ON                   |
+--------------------------+----------------------+
```

However I have not touched the my.cnf as in the instructions it is not mentioned. Do I have to do something additional?

My MariaDB version is

```
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.9-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

On centos7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved the issue, I am using centos7 and i had to:

1.) add this in /etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf

```
[mysqld]
bind-address=0.0.0.0

[galera]

wsrep_on=ON
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so
binlog_format=ROW
wsrep_cluster_address='gcomm://'
wsrep_cluster_name='galera_cluster'
wsrep_node_name='node1'
```

2.) I had to disable selinux and firewalld to let the other nodes to connect to the cluster. (I know for production uses you should handle the selinux and firewall rules but in my case it was a test on a local machine, so if you use it for prod handle this properly)

3.) in the connecting nodes specify the /etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf with:

```
[mysqld]
bind-address=0.0.0.0

[galera]

wsrep_on=ON
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so
binlog_format=ROW
wsrep_cluster_address='gcomm://ip_of_the_master,ip_of_other_nodes'
wsrep_cluster_name='galera_cluster'
wsrep_node_name='nodeX'
```

Then start mysql service.

Now my cluster looks like this:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'wsrep_%';
+------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name                | Value                                                       |
+------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| wsrep_apply_oooe             | 0.000000                                                    |
| wsrep_apply_oool             | 0.000000                                                    |
| wsrep_apply_window           | 1.000000                                                    |
| wsrep_causal_reads           | 0                                                           |
| wsrep_cert_deps_distance     | 60.887500                                                   |
| wsrep_cert_index_size        | 24                                                          |
| wsrep_cert_interval          | 0.000000                                                    |
| wsrep_cluster_conf_id        | 73                                                          |
| wsrep_cluster_size           | 3                                                           |
| wsrep_cluster_state_uuid     | c44d1346-a5c3-11e5-9a68-ca1db8f95be1                        |
| wsrep_cluster_status         | Primary                                                     |
| wsrep_commit_oooe            | 0.000000                                                    |
| wsrep_commit_oool            | 0.000000                                                    |
| wsrep_commit_window          | 1.000000                                                    |
| wsrep_connected              | ON                                                          |
| wsrep_evs_delayed            |                                                             |
| wsrep_evs_evict_list         |                                                             |
| wsrep_evs_repl_latency       | 0/0/0/0/0                                                   |
| wsrep_evs_state              | OPERATIONAL                                                 |
| wsrep_flow_control_paused    | 0.000000                                                    |
| wsrep_flow_control_paused_ns | 0                                                           |
| wsrep_flow_control_recv      | 0                                                           |
| wsrep_flow_control_sent      | 0                                                           |
| wsrep_gcomm_uuid             | 3c438933-a727-11e5-b2f2-f659b1338a74                        |
| wsrep_incoming_addresses     | 100.120.88.245:3306,100.120.88.244:3306,100.120.88.246:3306 |
| wsrep_last_committed         | 400                                                         |
| wsrep_local_bf_aborts        | 0                                                           |
| wsrep_local_cached_downto    | 1                                                           |
| wsrep_local_cert_failures    | 0                                                           |
| wsrep_local_commits          | 391                                                         |
| wsrep_local_index            | 0                                                           |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue       | 0                                                           |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue_avg   | 0.071429                                                    |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue_max   | 2                                                           |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue_min   | 0                                                           |
| wsrep_local_replays          | 0                                                           |
| wsrep_local_send_queue       | 0                                                           |
| wsrep_local_send_queue_avg   | 0.000000                                                    |
| wsrep_local_send_queue_max   | 1                                                           |
| wsrep_local_send_queue_min   | 0                                                           |
| wsrep_local_state            | 4                                                           |
| wsrep_local_state_comment    | Synced                                                      |
| wsrep_local_state_uuid       | c44d1346-a5c3-11e5-9a68-ca1db8f95be1                        |
| wsrep_protocol_version       | 7                                                           |
| wsrep_provider_name          | Galera                                                      |
| wsrep_provider_vendor        | Codership Oy <info@codership.com>                           |
| wsrep_provider_version       | 25.3.9(r3387)                                               |
| wsrep_ready                  | ON                                                          |
| wsrep_received               | 182                                                         |
| wsrep_received_bytes         | 17414                                                       |
| wsrep_repl_data_bytes        | 52304                                                       |
| wsrep_repl_keys              | 1183                                                        |
| wsrep_repl_keys_bytes        | 18664                                                       |
| wsrep_repl_other_bytes       | 0                                                           |
| wsrep_replicated             | 400                                                         |
| wsrep_replicated_bytes       | 96568                                                       |
| wsrep_thread_count           | 2                                                           |
+------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you. I had same issue it took me half day.